# How can I set Default value for DropDownList for DEPT_ID = 2 in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I set Default value for DropDownList for DEPT_ID = 2 in MVC view
this is index action

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS = db.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.Where(dept=>dept.DEPT_ID==2).Include(d => d.Department).Include(d => d.Hospital).Include(d => d.LabTests_hajj).Include(d => d.sys_users);
            return View(dEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS.ToList());
        }
```

this is CREATE action there is 4 Viewbag select list read data from foreign key tables

```
      public ActionResult Create()
            {
                
      ViewBag.DEPT_ID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Dept_id", "Dept_name");
        ViewBag.hospital_no = new SelectList(db.Hospitals, "Id", "hospital_name");
        ViewBag.TEST_ID = new SelectList(db.LabTests_hajj, "TestId", "TestName");
        ViewBag.user_id = new SelectList(db.sys_users, "user_id", "user_name");

         

   return View();
            }
```

This is complete VIEW :

```
@model warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutDashboard.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DEPT_ID, "DEPT_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DEPT_ID ,new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Text = "Clinical Chemistry ", Value = "2" } }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DEPT_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TEST_ID, "TEST_ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("TEST_ID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TEST_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TESTS_MORNING, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TESTS_MORNING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TESTS_MORNING, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TESTS_EVENING, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DATE, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DATE, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DATE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.hospital_no, "hospital_no", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("hospital_no", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.hospital_no, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_id, "user_id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("user_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

appreciate your help .

I updated the question and added the complete view code
can you check please
another question when I select dept_id = 2 , how can I in the ViewBag.TEST_ID only show the tests belongs to there dept_id = 2 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't enough sample code in your question to say for sure, and it's a bit confusing because you have added the `SelectList` data to the ViewBag using the same property name, but it looks like you have a viewmodel with a `DEPT_ID` property.

You could set `DEPT_ID = 2` in the Controller and pass the model to the View e.g.

```cs
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.DEPT_ID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "Dept_id", "Dept_name");
    var vm = new warehouse.Models.DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS();
    vm.DEPT_ID = 2;
    return View(vm);
}
```

For your other questions, I would recommend having a look at the [Microsoft Razor Pages with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) and [ASP.NET Core MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) tutorials.

Comment: this code created by default when I created the controller I selected MVC 5 controller with views using entity framework , what is the sample code you need more I will post ? what is the ViewModel() ?

Comment: More of the View, in particular what the model is declared as. That is your viewmodel.

Comment: I added more codes , the create action has 4 selectlist how to handle it when return the view , and the Viewmodel class DEPARTMENTS_STATISTICS thank you

Comment: You didn't add any more of the View

Comment: I updated the question , also I need when select dept_id = 2 in the second TEST_ID list show tests for dept_=2 only how can I do that thank you

Comment: See updated answer for setting the default value.